# Exception when updating UI element from some work done on separate thread

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, thread-safety, .net-2.0

I have a UI application that simply recursively search for particular file type and display the results in a list box. However it is causing the classic UI freeze problem so I am trying to do the search in separate thread and the update the listbox in UI thread. I have two solutions, one of these is causing an exception while other is working great. Problem is I don’t understand why solution #1 is throwing exception.

**Solution #1**
This throws IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array at the call to this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { this.lsResult.Items.Add(files[startingIndex].ToString()); }));

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.lsResult.Items.Clear();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        new Thread(BeginSearch).Start();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }


    private void BeginSearch()
    {
        string searchPath = this.textBox1.Text; // C:\*.txt
        RecurseDirectory(searchPath);

    }
    private void RecurseDirectory(string searchPath)
    {
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(searchPath);
        string search = Path.GetFileName(searchPath);

        if (directory == null || search == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, search);
        int startingIndex = 0;
        while (startingIndex < files.Length)
        {


            //IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                this.lsResult.Items.Add(files[startingIndex].ToString());
            }));
            Interlocked.Increment(ref startingIndex);
        }

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
        foreach (string d in directories)
        {
            RecurseDirectory(Path.Combine(d, search));
        }
    }

}
```

**Solution #2**
This works great.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate void FileListDelegate(string[] files);
    private FileListDelegate _FileListDelegate;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _FileListDelegate = new FileListDelegate(ShowFileNames);
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.lsResult.Items.Clear();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        new Thread(BeginSearch).Start();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }


    private void BeginSearch()
    {
        string searchPath = this.textBox1.Text;
        RecurseDirectory(searchPath);

    }
    private void RecurseDirectory(string searchPath)
    {
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(searchPath);
        string search = Path.GetFileName(searchPath);

        if (directory == null || search == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, search);
        this.BeginInvoke(_FileListDelegate, new object[] { files });

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
        foreach (string d in directories)
        {
            RecurseDirectory(Path.Combine(d, search));
        }
    }

    void ShowFileNames(string[] files)
    {
        foreach(string file in files)
            this.lsResult.Items.Add(file.ToString());
    }

}
```

Both solutions look very same to me and I don’t understand why #1 is throwing exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing over the variable `startingIndex` in your first solution.  It's important to realize that closures *close over variables, not over values*.  The method will use the value of `startingIndex` *when the delegate is eventually executed*, which could be at some point in the distant future, instead of using the value of that variable *right now*.  You're constantly incrementing `startIndex` until it's set to a value past the end of the array, hence your index out of bounds errors when you end up executing code using that variable after all of those increments.

The smallest code change would be to simply take a copy of the variable *inside* of the loop that won't change ever.  Then close over *that* variable.

```
int index = startingIndex;
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    this.lsResult.Items.Add(files[index].ToString());
}));
```

Also note that you can greatly simplify your code by having the file system recursively traverse itself.  Just use `Directory.GetFiles(searchPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` instead of explicitly handling the recursion yourself, then you can just loop through those files using a `foreach` and add each file to the UI.

Comment: thanks. One side question is that i have added a cancel button. In its event handler, i am setting a boolean flag to true. But for some reason i am never hitting the event handler when i try to click on cancel. Given that my processing is happening in separate thread, click button shouldn't be locked and should respond to user clicks, correct?

Comment: @PaulSnow You're performing a lot of invokes to the UI thread, which is going to be keeping it pretty busy, inhibiting other UI actions from taking place.  You should most likely use `Invoke`, rather than `BeginInvoke`, to prevent more than one UI action from being scheduled at a time.

Comment: well i am doing BeginInvoke to do UI update on UI thread. How can I do just Invoke? Am I misunderstanding something here

Comment: @PaulSnow You replace `BeginInvoke` with `Invoke` and then you're done.

Comment: worked like a charm :) Just to make sure i understand it correct BeginInvoke wasn't dispatching it to UI thread?

Comment: @PaulSnow It most certainly will.  If it it didn't, you'd get an exception for accessing a UI object from a non-UI thread.  Why don't you take some time to look at the documentation of both methods, and do some research on when each option should be used; it should give you a pretty clear indication of the difference.